# $Class.getResource failed from fat jar packed by maven shade plugin

Tags: java, scala, maven, maven-shade-plugin

My java/scala program requires support from a javescript code snippet. So I put it in my resource folder:

```
resources
|- sizzle.js
```

And in my pom.xml to explicitly include it in the fat/uber jar compiled by maven shade plugin:

```
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                            <resource>resources</resource>
                            <file>sizzle.js</file>
                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>
```

(I know this is unnecessary, but either way it will fail me)

When I try to read the javascript snippet from my source code:

```
sizzleSource = IOUtils.toString(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("sizzle.js"));
```

it works perfectly when running in IDE, but I get null pointer exception when executing the fat jar:

```
...
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:894)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:879)
...
```

So why maven shade plugin fail in this case? I'm able to see sizzle.js in the root dir of the fat jar, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: `SomeFatJarClass.getResource("/sizzle.js")` uses `Class.getResource`, with a relative, or here explicit absolute path. Should that work, it is a ClassLoader problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `sizzle.js` ends up at the root of your final jar, so you need to access it via :

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/sizzle.js"));
```

The method [`ClassLoader.getResource(name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) needs an absolute path to look for a resource.

Comment: Thank you! But this will break the unit test when executed in IDE, as getResource("/sizzle.js") cannot get files in /source folder if not running in the fat jar. Is there a solution that can handle both cases?

Comment: You should place `sizzle.js` under `src/main/resources`. This way, it will be automatically added to the uber jar (will end up at the root of the final jar so you won't have to manually add it) and it will not break your unit test (if you access this file with `"/sizzle.js"`).

Comment: that's exactly where it is! yet "sizzle.js" can be evaluated fine but "/sizzle.js" will get me java.lang.NullPointerException. My IDE of IntelliJ IDEA ultimate should handle resources folder, as both src and test resources folder are marked clearly and sizzle.js is in both

Comment: Mmh, maybe this is a ClassLoader issue then. Try with the current class loader `getClass().getClassLoader()`.

Comment: The last solution works like magic! (Though I have to enclose it in non-static function but so far it doesn't cause any problem) The ContextClassLoader is indeed the culprit